# Do I need to install .DS_Store on Windows?

Tags: ajax, file

I am trying to create a blog with comments using AJAX, but there's a part of the tutorial where I had to install this file `.ds_store` and other files as well. In this tutorial, they are using Mac.

Do I need this file on the system I'm working on, i.e. Windows 8?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need it and you can't, it's a OSX's specific feature.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store